# PHP "save dialog" for file received from web service

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using [WSO2 WS Framework](http://wso2.com/products/web-services-framework/php) and I managed to run example in which web service returns an image as a MTOM attachment which is then saved by the client using file_put_contents(...) command.

**Service:**

```
<?php

function sendAttachment($msg){
$responsePayloadString = <<<XML
    <ns1:download xmlns:ns1="http://wso2.org/wsfphp/samples/mtom">
        <ns1:fileName>test.jpg</ns1:fileName>
            <ns1:image xmlmime:contentType="image/jpeg" xmlns:xmlmime="http://www.w3.org/2004/06/xmlmime">
                <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:myid1"></xop:Include>
            </ns1:image>
    </ns1:download>
XML;
$f = file_get_contents("test.jpg");                                        

$responseMessage = new WSMessage($responsePayloadString, 
        array( "attachments" => array("myid1" => $f)));  
return $responseMessage;    
}

$operations = array("download" => "sendAttachment");

$service = new WSService(array("operations" => $operations, "useMTOM" => TRUE));

$service->reply();

?>
```

**Client:**

```
<?php

$requestPayloadString = '<download></download>';

try {

$client = new WSClient(
    array( "to" => "http://SPLINTER/MTOM/service.php",
           "useMTOM" => TRUE,
           "responseXOP" => TRUE));

$requestMessage = new WSMessage($requestPayloadString);                    
$responseMessage = $client->request($requestMessage);

printf("Response = %s \n", $responseMessage->str);

$cid2stringMap = $responseMessage->attachments;
$cid2contentMap = $responseMessage->cid2contentType;
$imageName;
if($cid2stringMap && $cid2contentMap){
    foreach($cid2stringMap as $i=>$value){
        $f = $cid2stringMap[$i];
        $contentType = $cid2contentMap[$i];
        if(strcmp($contentType,"image/jpeg") ==0){
            $imageName = $i."."."jpg";
            if(stristr(PHP_OS, 'WIN')) {
                file_put_contents($imageName, $f);
            }else{
                file_put_contents("/tmp/".$imageName, $f);
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    printf("attachments not received ");
}

} catch (Exception $e) {

if ($e instanceof WSFault) {
    printf("Soap Fault: %s\n", $e->Reason);
} else {
    printf("Message = %s\n",$e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

Instead of that I would like to open a "Save dialog" to choose between opening or saving the file. When searching for solution I read about setting heders like:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg"');
```

But it didn't work well. "Save dialog" poped up, but when image couldn't be opened saying that file is empty.

Actually I don't understand very good how this MTOM attachments thing is working. In client code, I think $f is a string and when I do printf($f) it prints 0(zero) so how can I save this string as an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use that headers, you have to output the file content, not save it somewhere.

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.jpg"');

// Output file. This must be the ONLY output of the whole script
echo $rawFileContents;
```

The basics is that at the moment you have your whole file content loaded in a variable (and it seems is `$f` in your code), you output it instead of write it in a file (as I think you're doing now). So, the three lines of code I gave you should replace the `file_put_contents()` calls.

Instead, if you want to save the file in your `/tmp` folder, ok, do it, but then use instead

```
header('Location: /tmp/' . $imageName);
```

This way you redirect the user browser directly to the saved file, and let users do what they want with it.

Comment: Where in my code exactly should I put that header code you provided? Should I used any other headers too or just this one? As I understand I have to remove file_put_contents($imageName, $f); right? Also, thank you for extremely fast answer.

Comment: I admit your code is quite messy and I did not read it all. The basics is that at the moment you have your whole file content loaded in a variable (and it seems is `$f`), you can put it in a file (as I think you're doing) or output it. So, the three lines of code I gave you should replce the `file_put_contents()` call.

Comment: It seems that the file is extracted from the attachments in the first line of foreach loop. Like you said - $f. I replaced file_put_contents() with your 3 lines but there is no difference. You are right, I want to save this image from $f to the file through "save dialog". Do I have to change anything else to make this work, because it is still saying that the file is empty when trying to open the image.

Comment: If I do printf($f) it writes 0. But file_put_contents($imageName, $f);
saves the image correctly. That's what I would like to do but with "save dialog" and not automatically.

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid. Of course your 3 lines of code did the trick but I had to rename $rawFileContents to $f :) Thanks for your help!!